# Custom Keyboard Crash

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, crash, custom-keyboard, xcode7

I made a custom keyboard. Everything works fine except of two things:
(I am using Xcode 7 and am testing the app on my iPhone 5.)

1. When I turn the device from portrait to landscape or the other way round
   sometimes it does not change the formation and crashs.

I wonder why this happens only sometimes and not every time the first time.

2. When my phone is not connected to Xcode it does not work like
   when it is connected to the computer.
   It crashs when I was not in the app for around 5-10 seconds and I open
   it again then.
   It does not pop up again and a restart is necessary.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using a beta version? Have you tried running the project from Xcode 6.x on your iPhone 5?

Comment: With Xcode 7 I can test the app on my personal phone without paying in a developer program. So I am still using iOS 8.

Comment: An addition: When I tilt it directly after the build to landscape and back without tapping something on it it also crashes with the formation issue.